# what happens if I commit to master after a git rebase

Tags: git, github

#### Alias I'm using

```
alias cm='git checkout master'
alias com='git add . ; git commit -m'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gl='git log'
alias graph='git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline'
```

My Steps

```
git init rebase-test
cd rebase-test/
echo "master file 1">file1.txt
com "master add file1"
gc -b feature-1
echo "feature-1 file 2">file2.txt
com "feature-1 add file 2"
echo "master file 3">file3.txt
com "feature-1 add file 3"
cm
echo "master file 4">file4.txt
com "master add file 4"
echo "master file 5">file5.txt
com "master add file 5"
```

```

Then I checkout the feature-1 and rebase

```
gb feature-1
git rebase master
```

This is the output I get when I log using

```
git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline



* 2f0e025 (HEAD -> feature-1) feature-1 add file 3
* ae4921b feature-1 add file 2
* 3e72852 (master) master add file 5
* 859afc0 master add file 4
* becc58d master add file1
```

Then after I add a file to master branch and commit again I get this output for git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline

```
* 3a55d83 (HEAD -> master) master add file 6
| * 2f0e025 (feature-1) feature-1 add file 3
| * ae4921b feature-1 add file 2
|/  
* 3e72852 master add file 5
* 859afc0 master add file 4
* becc58d master add file1
```

It's like the rebase was reverted. I expected the master branch to stay linear ..
What's the point of rebase then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... What's the point of rebase then?

The point of `git rebase` is to copy commits, and then abandon the originals in favor of the new copies.  This is not especially useful by itself, but it has consequences that may *later* be useful.

Note that any *other* repository that has the original (pre-copy-step) commits, still has those original commits, and does not yet have the new commits.  Connecting the repository in which you made the copies, to some pre-copy repository, will usually cause the two Gits to *combine* the two sets of commits, so that you have both the pre- *and* the post-copy commits, sitting around ready to work with.  It will then be all too easy to `git merge` the two sets together.  This leads to a general rule one can use here: *Try not to rebase **published** commits.*

(There's a more sophisticated version of this same rule that reads: *Make sure, before rebasing (i.e., copying) published commits, that all parties that will deal with these commits understand how and why rebase copies commits, and how to deal with the after-effects.*  Note that recent Git versions handle some of this automatically, using the `--fork-point` option  that is available in both `git rebase` and `git merge-base`.  It's still best to make sure that everyone has agreed to this, and understands how it all works.)

---

We do not have the `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` output from *before* your rebase.  (If I repeat your commands I'll get all new hash IDs, since the hash IDs encode the commit author's name *and* the time down to the second.)  We have this one, from afterward:

```
* 2f0e025 (HEAD -> feature-1) feature-1 add file 3
* ae4921b feature-1 add file 2
* 3e72852 (master) master add file 5
* 859afc0 master add file 4
* becc58d master add file1
```

Note the hash IDs.  Here's my guess as to what it might look like before:

```
* 3e72852 (master) master add file 5
* 859afc0 master add file 4
| * XXXXXXX (HEAD -> feature-1) feature-1 add file 3
| * YYYYYYY feature-1 add file 2
|/
* becc58d master add file1
```

Note the *different* hash IDs, and the fact that `YYYYYYY`'s parent is `becc58d`.

This means that, *before* the rebase, the history of commits in your repository ends with:

- commit `3e72852`: the final commit on `master`
- commit `XXXXXXX`: the final commit on `feature-1`

From these two final commits, we—and Git—can work backwards.  When we do, we arrive, in two steps, at `becc58d`, from either starting point.  So `becc58d` is the last common, shared commit on the two branches.

---

If we let single letters stand in for each of the commits, and draw the graph sideways with older commits on the left and newer ones on the right, we get this graph:

```
  D--E   <-- master
 /
A
 \
  B--C   <-- feature-1 (HEAD)
```

Once the rebase *finishes*, however, we have this:

```
        B'-C'  <-- feature-1 (HEAD)
       /
A--D--E   <-- master
 \
  B--C   [abandoned, but see the reflog for feature-1: `feature-1@{1}`]
```

That is, commits `B` and `C` are no longer visible without special binoculars (though you can use `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline feature-1@{1}` to see them), but the new copies `B'` and `C'`, which have hash IDs `ae4921b` and `2f0e025` respectively, *are* visible, and are found by starting where `feature-1` indicates, and working backwards.

The most recent commit that is on *both* branches `feature-1` and `master` is now `3e72852`, the one labeled `E` in the sideways drawing.  All three commits from here back to `becc58d` are all on *both* branches.

---

When you make your new commit `3a55d83` on `master`, this simply extends `master`.  Let's draw this in as commit `F`:

```
        B'-C'  <-- feature-1
       /
A--D--E------F   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Original commits `B` and `C` are probably still in there (they will stick around for at least 30 days by default) but since they are hard to see, we can stop drawing them.

If you wish to have `feature-1` follow commit `F`, you must rebase yet again, so as to copy commit `B'` to `B"` and `C'` to `C"`.  The parent of `B"` will be `F`, rather than `E`, and the parent of `C"` will be `B"`.

Comment: Thanks , I missed the part when I needed to merge after rebasing as Rebase is just changing the base of the branch.